# Ftp Windows Command Line Command Not Working

Tags: windows, cmd, download, ftp

I'm using Windows command line for getting some files from a ftp server.

I need to change the local directory during the session.

I tried using 'lcd' command but it's not working. I displayed that the command is executed correctly but when i download the files they are downloaded on another directory (default?).

Retyping 'lcd' to show the actual local directory i can see it does not change.

The code i used is written below

```
lcd C:\Myfolder\MySubFolder
```

I tryed also the cmd with administrative priviledges, but it is the same.

Thank You.

Comment: Well, does the local directory really exist?

Comment: Yes! I checked.

Comment: I got the same result. You can do `cd C:\Myfolder\MySubFolder` before running ftp, but if you really need to change it during session, then it is open question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. During my ftp session I need to use the mget command multiple times. So i need to change my local destination folder during the session. At this moment i firstly download all the files in a "temp" folder and then i move these files in their destination folders. But i use a lot of extra code.